# Reload Angular directive after send new data from form

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

It is possible to reload directive after send new data object to this directive? I have form to add new object and after this i want to reload my directive template. I use $scope.$watch but it's only work in first initialization.

Sorry that I don't have any JSFIDDLE example.

//EDIT

I implementation my directive like this:

```
function customDirective(){
    var directive = {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        data: '='
      },
      templateUrl: 'samplehtml',
      controller: 'SampleController',
      controllerAs: 'samCtrl'
    };
    return directive;
  }
```

and in my main view i call my directive like this:

```
<custom-directive data='myObject'></custom-directive>
```

and after send my form the 'myObject' have new parameteres but directive dont load new myObject data.

Comment: Pleas post all relevant code, if not a jsfiddle

Comment: try `data="$parent.myObject"`. If it works tell me i will provide you a full answer of what is happening

Comment: Hmm, I think $parent is not a answer because I have access to data in my main controller. SampleController I use for other situations

Comment: Can you show me your template? I would like to see how you are accessing data inside the template. And also, didnt you try the same thing using a link function?